# What is the name for the phenomenon or process by which the brain knows what "it" in a sentence refers to?

Tags: terminology, pronouns, cognitive-linguistics

What is the name for the phenomenon or process by which the brain knows what "it" in a sentence refers to ? 
For example : I left my book on the table but when I came back, IT wasn't there.

Comment: The phenomenon?  Sentience?  Memory?  I don't think this is the right forum for discussion of psychological phenomena.  However, "the book" in this example would be called **the antecedent**, ie the thing that is referred back to.

Comment: I guess, just as in computer science, we'd call it *dereferencing*?

Comment: Do you mean the table has gone? )))

Answer (score 9):

Within some branches of linguistics, it may be referred to as any of the following:

- reference resolution
- pronoun resolution
- pronoun reference resolution
- anaphora resolution

Notice that reference resolution is a more general term which includes pronoun resolution.

Comment: The whole topic comes up in all branches of linguistics as _coreference_. I.e, when there are two referring NPs in an utterance that both refer to the same individual, they are said to be coreferential. Nouns and pronouns are NPs, so this covers personal pronoun _it_, among others. It does **not**, however, cover Extraposition _it_ (_It's too bad you have to leave_), weather _it_ (_It's supposed to rain today_), or distance _it_ (_It's a long way to Tipperary_), all of which are non-referential.

Comment: . anaphora/**cataphora** resolution (the 'antecedent' may follow the pronoun).

Comment: @John Lawler - It is worth considering that 'weather it' refers to a non-overloaded [pro]noun such as 'now' (to serve as the topic under which time and nature phenomena are stored).  Extraposition and distance 'it' can also be evaluated as cataphoric 'normal it'.

Comment: @AmI *Now* is a preposition, not a pronoun.

Comment: @Araucaria - 'now' is NOT a preposition.  It is often called an adverb, but that is because it is a temporal [pro]noun, so it is often used adverbially.

Comment: @AmI It IS! Can you provide any grammatical/syntactic evidence that a) it's a pronoun or that b) it isn't a preposition? (notice how my capitals made me correct and you wrong there ;)) I have several pages.

Comment: What in the world would make anyone think _now_ is either a preposition or a pronoun? If you don't need a special category for deictic temporals, then _now_ seems much more adverbial than either of those choices.

Comment: @JohnLawler "Adverbial" is a term primarily relating to grammatical relations, isn't it. And adverbials are normally preposition phrases. And since Jespersen, there're more and more linguists who agree that prepositions are a group of words just like nouns, verbs etc that can take different complements or sometimes none at all. It is the fact that *now* has no properties which would make one think that it's an adverb, but loads that would make one think that it's a preposition that make it likely to be a preposition. A small selection of this evidence is ...

Comment: @JohnLawler  a) it's modifiable by the specialised adverb *right* which modifies prep but not adverb, b) it can function as a predicative complement c) it can postmodify nouns, d) it can't be modified by *very*, e) it can take a content clause as a complement. Erm, I've run out of steam. I can give you more but I would have to go and look it up again. (I don't mind doing that, if it would be of interest). CaGEL talks about it a bit.

Comment: @Araucaria - I'm sorry for the CAPS -- just look at the definition of 'now' and you will see 'adverb', not 'preposition'. "I am now the speaker" means "I am the speaker, now", or "Now, I am the speaker", etc.  'Now' can move around because it is adverbial.  I call deictic words like 'now', 'today', and 'Monday' [pro]nouns rather than adverbs, because I see them as sometimes being used with an elided preposition ('on', 'at', etc.), fitting your definition of adverbial.  John simply lumps all single-word adverbials as 'adverbs', which works grammatically but isn't semantic...

Comment: @AmI No worries re the caps! Back to business: adverbial and adverb are a million miles apart. One's basically a grammatical relation. The other is a part of speech. But what we were talking about was really parts of speech, not grammatical relations. The reason it can move around like that is that it's a modifier [read adjunct or adverbial]. Notice that preposition phrases are also modifiers. (btw, I'd advise never to use dictionaries for grammatical information, it isn't what they're there for!)

Comment: @Araucaria - I know all that..., but a preposition takes an object (in the box), which may be elided (in [the box]).  How does 'now' work as a preposition?  Do you get what I said about elided prepositions ([on] Monday) and my interpretation ([at] now), which makes 'now' a noun used adverbially with an elided dummy preposition (at)?  PS: since adverbials are merely info whose topic is the verb rather than the subject, there need not be a category of 'adverb' except perhaps for adjective+'ly' (because the adverbial marker is attached to the adjective).

Comment: @AmI No,  prepositions don't necessarily take objects.

Comment: *now* can be considered [a pro-preposition](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/298405/59258)

Comment: @aml Take a look here: [link](https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/now) Huddleston & Pullum also call it a prep in their award-winning CGEL.

Comment: @BillJ , Wikipedia's finally good for something!  ;)

Comment: @Araucaria haha! I did wonder if GKP was editing it, but that's a bit far-fetched. One thing is absolutely 100% certain and that is that it is not a noun!

Comment: @BillJ (apart from possibly in "the here and now" or similar)

Comment: Like "the ups and downs" and "the ins and outs". Interesting!

Comment: @BillJ - that Wiktionary link has 'now' and 'then' as prepositions, but 'today' as a pronoun.  Please give a sample sentence where swapping 'now' with 'today' is ungrammatical.  OK, "now it is Monday" is preferred over "now is Monday" -- I will rethink my world!

Comment: @amI There are several cases where _now_ and _today_ are not swappable (apart from purely semantic cases), such as the ‘impatient segue’ use (“Now leave me alone and get to work!” — “*Today leave me alone and get to work”) or the placative use (“Now now boys, let's not argue” — “*Today today boys, let's not argue”). Then again, I'm not sure even Pullum would classify those _now_’s as prepositions. Perhaps more relevantly: “I've spent most of today playing Angry Birds” — “*I've spent most of now playing Angry Birds”.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41237/discussion-on-answer-by-araucaria-what-is-the-name-for-the-phenomenon-or-process).

Comment: @aml Unlike the temporal prepositions "now" and "then", the pronouns "yesterday", "today" etc have genitive forms: today's, "yesterday's" etc. So you get _Have you seen today's news?_ but not _*have you seen now's news?_

Comment: @curiousdannii - thank you for your thoughtful answers.  Since 'preposition' is a loaded word, 'pro-preposition' is ugly. I would accept 'pro-reference'.  Everyone accepts 'now' to mean 'at the present time'; whereas I had considered it to mean '[at] the present time'.